# What are the symptoms for kundalini awakening?

Tags: yoga, kundalini

Kundalini can be achieved by different means (yoga or devotion or deep thinking).

Are there any symptoms or experiences the human undergoes before kundalini awakening? If yes, then what are the **symptoms that are mentioned in scriptures**?

Comment: You could read the twenty yoga upanishads, or the tantric agamas. Though the symptoms differ according to temperament. The books like gheranda samhita, hatha yoga pradipika, siva samhita may also be helpful. As for a modern experience and the cautions involved, see the books by Swami Sivananda on Kundalini Yoga or the popular account by Gopi Krishna